# How to send input values to terminal without using subprocess or pexpect modules

Tags: python

I am trying to write unit tests for a python script. My script takes user input whether proxy credentials are required or not. I have seen several [answer-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510318/send-input-to-python-subprocess-without-waiting-for-result), [answer-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408377/how-can-i-get-terminal-output-in-python), [answer-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) like executing with subprocess and pexpect. But my intention is that after taking user input, I have to execute other functions in the script. So executing the script doesn't help. My python script is below. Can someone provide me suggestions or with a way to achieve this?

```
import getpass
class ProxyDetails:
    def __init__(self,option):
        self.option = option
        self.proxy_option = self.get_web_proxy_details()
        self.call_request()
        self.parse_test()

    def get_web_proxy_details(self):
        if self.option == "Default":
            choice = raw_input("Enter credentials : Y/N ").lower()
            if choice.lower() == "y":
                self.proxy_username = getpass.getpass("Enter Username for Proxy : ")
                self.proxy_password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password for Proxy : ")
                self.requireProxyCredentials = "Y"
            elif choice.lower() == "n":
                print("credentials are not present ")
        else:
            print("proxy is none ")

    def call_request(self):
        # this method will do API call
        pass
    def parse_test(self):
        #this method will parse the json
        pass

obj=ProxyDetails(option="Default")
```

I want to send input value when `Enter credentials : Y/N`  is prompted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239002/enter-to-raw-input-automatically) question.I am not deleting this as it might be useful for someone else.

```
import sys
import StringIO
f1 = sys.stdin
f = StringIO.StringIO('n') 
sys.stdin = f
obj=ProxyDetails(option="Default")
sys.stdin = f1
```